# Free alternative to Targetprocess?

Tags: project-management, collaboration, targetprocess

We are searching for a free alternative to TargetProcess.

We would like to use the following features:

- Collaboration Software
- Project Management
- Gantt Charts
- maybe SVN/ GIT support
- Usual things like release plans, boards & charts

Does anybody know a good free software for about 10 or more people?

Answer (score 3):

[TargetProcess](http://www.targetprocess.com) has no Gantt Charts. As for free alternatives, [Trello](https://trello.com/) is pretty cool for Kanban projects. If you run Scrum, you can try [IceScrum](http://www.agile-tools.net/agileprojectmanagement/icescrum.aspx), it is a decent free tool that has everything to plan releases, sprints and track progress.

Comment: Why downvoting? That's a good answer. Also I want to add links from another deleted answer [Kanban Tool](http://kanbantool.com) and [AgileZen](http://www.agilezen.com/) have (very) limited but free versions. And there is a very nice alternative by ThoughtWorks - [Mingle](http://www.thoughtworks.com/products/mingle-agile-project-management/choose-edition) which if free for small teams.

Answer (score -2):

umm, something along the lines of http://alternativeto.net/software/targetprocess ?